# XeLaTeX forward search does not work properly when a paragraph only have one word

Tags: xetex, forward-inverse-search

*remark: I upgraded to TeX Live 2022 and still can reproduce this problem. It's weird how commenters using same TeX Live 2022 and cannot reproduce*

---

When a paragraph has only one word, forward synctex search is wrong when compiled with XeLaTeX.

1. Create a TeX file (named for example `a.tex`)

   ```latex
   %! TEX program = xelatex
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   text text

   a

   b

   text text

   \end{document}
   ```

   Note that line 6 is the first `text text` line, line 8 is the `a` line, and line 12 is the second `text text` line.
2. Compile

   ```bash
   xelatex -synctex=1 a.tex
   ```
3. Try to obtain the coordinate with the synctex.

   ```bash
   synctex view -i 6:1:./a.tex -o a.pdf
   synctex view -i 8:1:./a.tex -o a.pdf
   synctex view -i 12:1:./a.tex -o a.pdf
   ```

   Note that the first 2 output are identical, although it points to 2 different paragraphs.
4. Alternatively, open zathura and highlight the line in zathura.

   ```bash
   zathura a.pdf
   zathura --synctex-forward 6:1:./a.tex a.pdf  # first line is highlighted, correct
   zathura --synctex-forward 8:1:./a.tex a.pdf  # first line is still highlighted, wrong
   zathura --synctex-forward 12:1:./a.tex a.pdf  # last line is highlighted, correct
   ```

The result is correct for LuaLaTeX. Is this a XeLaTeX bug?

---

XeLaTeX version:

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 71.1; using 71.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.12; using 1.2.12
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.12.0; using 2.12.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 4.2.0; using 4.3.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.0; using 2.14.0
```

`synctex` version:

```
$ synctex
This is SyncTeX command line utility, version 1.5
SyncTeX ERROR: Missing options
usage: synctex <subcommand> [options] [args]
Synchronize TeXnology command-line client, version 1.21

The Synchronization TeXnology by Jérôme Laurens is a rather new feature of recent TeX engines.
It allows to synchronize between input and output, which means to
navigate from the source document to the typeset material and vice versa.

Available subcommands:
   view     to perform forwards synchronization
   edit     to perform backwards synchronization
   update   to update a synctex file after a dvi/xdv to pdf filter
   help     this help

Type 'synctex help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
There is also an undocumented test subcommand.
```

When I ctrl-click in zathura, the inverse search is correct, so it could be a synctex bug too, I don't know.

Comment: I tried, but I got different output in the first two cases.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either (using XeTeX from TeX Live 2022/dev though).